# Visual Studio2017でのjni.h

Tags: visual-studio, jni

VS2017で次のようなエラーがでてしまいました。
解決方法を教えてください

エラー LNK1107 ファイルが無効であるか、または壊れています: 0x120E3 を読み取れません。    opencampus  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\include\jni.h

Comment: どのような設定を行ったのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

すみません、こちらの質問は登録時に消えてしまったものだと思っていました。設定とはどういうことでしょうか？
sln自体は2年前にVisualC++2010にて作成されたもので、それをVS2017で動かしたいと思っております。その際にデバッグして実行したときにこのエラーが出てしまいます。
昔は出来ていたみたいなので、プログラム自体には問題はないと思います。
試しにと思いVisualC++2010でも試しているのですが、こちらでも同じエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: 質問した際とアカウントが分かれてしまったのですね。ヘルプセンターの[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)にアカウントを統合するやり方が書いてあるので、申請なさってみてください。

Comment: 先ほど、 CM チームに連絡しましたので、重複アカウントの場合は、対応され次第、マージされると思います。

Comment: すみません、いろいろとありがとうございます。